# Exim not sending email to our own email addresses

Tags: email, email-server, exim

Here is a situation.

We use google app for our emails. Our application is hosted at another host and this application sends out emails. The emails from the application are being sent fine to every email except our own email addresses.

Lets say our domain name is example.com, the emails to abc@examle.com is not getting delivered, but they are getting stored locally on the box only.

We are using exim as a mail server on the box where the application is deployed. We have also set up dc_relay_domains.

What could be missing? How do we make sure that the email to email addresses of our own domain names get delivered?

Answer (score 2):

```
man update-exim4.conf
   dc_other_hostnames
          is  used to build the local_domains list, together with "localhost".  This is the list of domains
          for which this machine should consider itself the final destination. The local_domains list  ends
          up in the macro MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS.
```

check in autogenerated exim.conf for smth like this:

```
dnslookup:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8
  no_more
```

This means that message is routed through remote delivery (remote_smtp transport) if domain in rcpt address is different than local_domains. If not, message goes to another router, some router accepts it and in your case it ends up in local delivery transport.

I'm sorry, but in your case you should go full hog on Exim and learn configuring Exim manually. update-exim4.conf is for typical cases.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like your local exim has been configured incorrectly, with your domain name as a domain which should be considered as a final destination (as detailed in the previous reply.) If you are using exim on a Debian server, with the autogenerated configuration, you should reconfigure using the command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

and either (preferrably) specify that there is no local mail and send using a smarthost, see:

http://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4

or alternativly choose:

```
internet site; mail is sent and received directly using SMTP
```

and make sure that you do NOT specify your own domain when asked:

```
Please enter a semicolon-separated list of recipient domains for which this machine 
should consider itself the final destination. These domains are commonly called 
'local domains'. The local hostname and 'localhost' are always added to the list 
given here.
```

Here's an alternative, with screenshots, which should help you achieve what you need:

http://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-debian-6-squeeze